# Find indirect train connections

Tags: c++, loops

I have to find train journeys between two given city codes, if there is no direct route then I should find an indirect route via other journeys. If I want to go from A to B, I might have to go from A to C to B.

My file for the train routes is of form: departure code destination code company price time
This looks at direct routes, between two city codes.

Now I've used the following loop for direct connections, and it works, I just need help with the indirect connections.

```
// load file data into v1

string dep, dest;
cout << "\n\tEnter the departure: ";
cin >> dep;
cout << "\n\tEnter the destination: ";
cin >> dest;

for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i) {
    // Departure() and Destination(), return the departure/destination codes
    if (v1[i].Departure() == dep && v1[i].Destination() == dest)
          // here I find all the direct routes
    else
         // indirect routes dealt with here
}
```

I think for indirect routes, I have to in the else part deal with them. But I'm struggling to see how I would do it, I think I have to look at the where the first departure's destination and match this with my given dest.

Comment: Forget about the code -- it doesn't matter whether you use C++, Java, FORTRAN, or COBOL.  Study graph theory and work out an algorithm.  Do this before you do any "real" coding (though playing around with coding algorithms to get the "feel" of them is OK).

Comment: This is proof how deceptive computer science is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have there, is a graph.

There are many ways to find *a* path, many to find the *shortest* path and many to find the *cheapest* path.

This is not a simple else statement but I would recommend you reading up these:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem

Comment: I don't need the shortest or cheapest path, I just need all paths, I will deal with them later on.

Comment: You still cannot find those paths with a simple if/else statement. You need to do more than a single loop.

Comment: You will need recursion or loops.

Comment: Yes I need further loops, but struggling to see my starting point.

Comment: You will end up with an algorithm that checks if you can currently reach the final node from the set of nodes you have already reached. If not, the set is expanded by adding the neighbours of the nodes in your current set.

Comment: another good one to start of : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you read the following essay (it is very short):

http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs.html

It is written by Guido von Rossum, the creator of the Python programming language.

I like it because it discusses how to implement graphs using dictionaries (`std::map`, in C++ parlance), and provides very short, effective implementations of `find_path`, `find_all_paths`, and `find_shortest_path`. Given that they are implemented in Python, translating them to C++ is straightforward (because Python is easy to read; consider it pseudocode rather than *the Python solution*).

For example, the following code implements `find_all_paths`:

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
        path = path + [start]
        if start == end:
            return [path]
        if not graph.has_key(start):
            return []
        paths = []
        for node in graph[start]:
            if node not in path:
                newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
                for newpath in newpaths:
                    paths.append(newpath)
        return paths
```

Notice that it is a recursive implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at what Google has done for Google Transit in Google Maps: http://ad.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/files/transferpatterns.pdf.